# Requesting iAd BannerViews even after changing viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iad

I have an iAd banner that will continue to request ads even after I use a navigation controller to push a new view controller. How do I prevent this? I may have created the ad object incorrectly.

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.delegate = self;
[adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

CGRect frame = adView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - (frame.size.height);

adView.frame = frame;
```

Is that the proper way to create an ad banner for iAd? If not, could you please show me how to properly create an ad banner object?

```
-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get banner ad");
    adView.hidden = YES;
}

-(void) bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    NSLog(@"bannerView Will Load Ad");
}

-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    adView.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"bannerView Did Load Ad");
}

-(BOOL) bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    NSLog(@"Ad banner action");
    return YES;
}

-(void) bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    adView.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"bannerViewActionDidFinish");
}
```

And here are my banner view methods.

bannerViewWillLoadAd and bannerViewDidLoadAd keep getting called even after I push a new view controller.

Edit: Also one more quick question. The banner view usually requests for another ad about 5 minutes after the new view controller is pushed and usually requests every 30 seconds when it's on the view controller that I want the ads to be in. This 5 minute interval is very odd to me. Is there a reason why it's waiting that long afterwards to request an ad?

Comment: on the bannerViewWillLoadAd you are adding it to the view but you never remove it. bannerViewWillLoadAd gets called every time its about to load an ad, so you should add it to your view somewhere else, since you are using "hidden" to hide and show the ad banner

Answer (score 0):

The creation of the banner looks correct. Alternatively, you could be doing it in your XIB/Storyboard but that is not necessary.

you need to clear out the adbanners delegate on your viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear view controller lifecycle method.
conversely, you could be setting it back in the viewDidAppear method so it will receive ads again when you come back to that view controller.

this would prevent messages coming across while another view controller is the main one on your stack. otherwise you may get crashes if you do not clear out the delegate, or release the banner (if you are not using ARC) when you are on a different view controller.

Comment: If I were to go with your 2nd recommendation how would I do it? Would I remove the ad banner object from super view when the view controller changes and then add it again in the viewDidAppear method?

Comment: you dont necessarily need to remove the adBanner when you load a new view controller onto the stack. you just need to manage it the same way on both add and removal. if, for instance, you want to init and add it on the viewDidAppear, you should remove it on the viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear. or you could init it in the viewDidLoad and and place it in the view then handle the delegate stuff and hidden aspect in the view lifecycle.

Comment: Nevermind. I decided to set the adbannerview delegate to nil and then setting the delegate back to the view controller when it was popped back. ads are not loaded. However, there is an error that occurs. It doesn't crash the program but this along with some other errors were logged: [AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner" UserInfo=0x10afb4c40